# prevent input event firing on each input / lazy input?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a textfield component that takes a string as a parameter and fires an input event on input. The consuming component is then able to update this value.

This input component uses this sample code

```html
    <template>
      <v-text-field label="Your input here" :value="name" @input="input"></v-text-field>
    </template>

    <script>
    export default {
      props: {
        name: {
          type: String,
          required: true
        }
      },
      methods: {
        input: function(v) {
          this.$emit("input", v);
        }
      }
    };
    </script>
```

The consuming component could use this sample code

```html
    <template>
      <v-app>
        <v-card>
          <v-card-title>Your name is: {{name}}</v-card-title>
          <NameInput :name="name" @input="fieldUpdated"/>
        </v-card>
      </v-app>
    </template>

    <script>
    import NameInput from "./components/NameInput";

    export default {
      components: {
        NameInput
      },
      data: function() {
        return {
          name: "The initial name"
        };
      },
      methods: {
        fieldUpdated: function(name) {
          this.name = name;
        }
      }
    };
    </script>
```

This approach works really fine but let's assume the `NameInput` component would handle IDs and the `fieldUpdated` method would fire an API call based on the provided ID input. The ID would be 8 characters long and when typing this ID the API call would fail 7 times before writing the correct ID.

I want to provide an option to prevent the input event firing on each input.

Let's say I would type in the ID and then jump to another input field and by leaving the field this field would fire the input event. How can I achieve that?

Comment: sounds like `@blur`

Comment: I found @blur in the docs now but this only returns me a bool. How do I pass back the current textfield value then?

Comment: You could use `@change`. Another option would be to look into debouncing.

Comment: how about check for length before making API call?

Comment: @ Jay Li, checking the length was only an example :) @ blur should be the correct event. But it might be, that @ change is even better

Comment: @ Husam Ibrahim if you want to, you can answer this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use a `change` event instead of `input`, which would only fire if the value in the text field changes and it loses focus ..

> The `change` event is fired for `input`, `select`, and `textarea`
>   elements when an alteration to the element's value is committed by the
>   user. Unlike the `input` event, the `change` event is not necessarily
>   fired for each alteration to an element's value.

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)

Another option would be to *debounce* the event, which would delay the invocation of the event handler if the event keeps repeating within a certain delay period. You could use lodash's [debounce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.debounce) method. For example ..

```
<template>
  <v-text-field label="Your input here" :value="name" @input="debouncedInput"></v-text-field>
</template>

<script>
  import debounce from 'lodash.debounce'

  export default {
    props: {
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      }
    },
    methods: {
      // debounce input 300ms
      debouncedInput: debounce(function(v) {
        this.$emit("input", v);
      }, 300)
    }
  };
</script>
```